# System.TypeInitializationException: in mono.

Tags: c#, mono, log4net, appdomain

I am trying to run .net windows application at mono. I have launched an exe in appdomain and later under that exe i am trying to launch an exe as a process. but exe fails to initialize logger. Logger is my custom interface on top of log4net. Here is the peace of code i am using to initialize logger.

```
log4net.GlobalContext.Properties["LogName"] = LogPath;
log4net.GlobalContext.Properties["LogDate"] = DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy_MM_dd_hh_mm_ss");    
XmlConfigurator.ConfigureAndWatch(new FileInfo(LoggerConfigurationFile)
```

The exception i am getting is following

```
System.TypeInitializationException: The type initializer for 'log4net.GlobalContext' threw an exception. ---> System.TypeInitializationException: The type initializer for 'log4net.Util.SystemInfo' threw an exception. ---> System.MissingMethodException: Method 'System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.get_AppSettings' not found.
  at log4net.Util.SystemInfo..cctor () [0x00031] in <dc05a9e165e94f46b41075fe5d8bfb59>:0 
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
  at log4net.GlobalContext..cctor () [0x00010] in <dc05a9e165e94f46b41075fe5d8bfb59>:0
```

But if i run the exe running under appdomain exe standalone for debug purpose the logger initialize perfectly.

Is the bug in mono not fully support Application domain of c#? Or there is something different.
Please help.

Comment: Which version of Mono are you using? that seems to me like you're using an ancient build.

Comment: here is what i am getting after running mono --version Mono JIT compiler version 4.6.2 (Stable 4.6.2.16/ac9e222 Tue Jan  3 11:48:26 UTC 2017)
Copyright (C) 2002-2014 Novell, Inc, Xamarin Inc and Contributors. www.mono-project.com
 TLS:           __thread
 SIGSEGV:       altstack
 Notifications: epoll
 Architecture:  amd64
 Disabled:      none
 Misc:          softdebug 
 LLVM:          supported, not enabled.
 GC:            sgen

Comment: Does the application creating the AppDomain have a reference to System.Configuration? If no try to add it. For what I know log4net works without problems as I use it myself, so there must be something messing the DLL loading inside the app domain, so adding a reference may resolve the problem.

Comment: yes it does have system.configuration reference. what i suspect that dll version i can see here is .NETFrameWork,Version=v4.6 for System.Confoguration and the log4net dll version is .NETFrameWork,Version=v4.0 so may be there is conflict?

Comment: @Gusman Thankyou so much for hint i have edited my app.config with following code <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
          <dependentAssembly>
              <assemblyIdentity name="System.Configuration" culture="neutral" publicKeyToken="b03f5f7f11d50a3a" />
              <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-4.0.0.0" newVersion="4.0.0.0" />
          </dependentAssembly>
      </assemblyBinding>    and logger has started working.

Comment: Glad it helped :)